# "Destination language" or "target language"?

Tags: american-english

For example, I translate a word from English to German. I call "English" "source language". Should I use "destination language" or "target language" for "German"?

Comment: It seems "destination language" is [rarer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=target+language%2Cdestination+language&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) than "target language" and is [often used](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22destination%20language%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) for the language migrants need to acquire when they change countries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both will be understood but ***target language*** sounds better and is probably the most commonly used expression to balance ***source language***.

For instance, the [wikipedia article about translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation) always uses the phrase "target language".

Answer (score 2):

It seems that "target language" is used more frequently. The [dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/target+language) records target language as:

> The language into which a text written in another language is to be translated.

However, it doesn't have any record of ["destination language"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/destination+language)

I think 'target language' would be better understood, and one would prefer to use 'target language', which is also the more correct term.